# Delay Javascript Loading

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, import

It is very important my page load quickly.  After loading I have a very javascript file that is not "needed" for anything until 10 seconds after page load.  How can I best load the external sheet without slowing down initial page load?

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //import Javascript
},500);
```

How would I import the javascript?
Would this even speed up page load?
Would some other technique work?

I'm not interested in analysis of whether this is "worth it."

(note: I am actually doing this in the context of a chrome extension, I don't think it will matter dramatically)

Comment: append a newly created script element and make `src` the url to your file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `async` attribute so that your script doesn't block the rendering of the page.

`<script src="path/script.js" async></script>`

And if your **really** don't want the script execute after the page is loaded, then you can also wrap your code in `window.onload`. This way the downloading of the script won't block rendering of the page and your code won't be executed until after the page loads.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript?hl=en

---

EDIT:

Another alternative that would be even better (if your browser supports it) would be `defer`, since it actually waits until the whole DOM is loaded, instead of `async` which only makes the loading of the script parallelized. Therefore:

`<script src="path/script.js" defer></script>`

Comment: For the OP's post, I feel like `defer` is better no? Because `async` will still block render whenever it gets loaded, so if `path/script.js` is small it won't really help that much

Comment: I agree. The reason I didn't go with `defer` is because according to MDN it hasn't been implemented by all major browsers. Although I'm having a hard time finding any other resources that verify that statement. Any idea about that?

Comment: Oh man, good point! I didn't think about that. I guess the OP says they're doing it in a Chrome extension though, and Chrome def has`defer`. I feel like most versions of IE probably don't though, you're right

Comment: That's true. Since it's for a Chrome extension it should work fine

Answer (score 10):

try this :

```
function loadJs(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
}
```

call the function  by

```
loadJs("your-script.js");
```

to load JS after a set time,

```
setTimeout(function(){
    loadJs("your-script.js");
},500);
```

you can also call it when all other components are loaded

```
window.onload = function() {
  loadJs("your-script.js");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like most analytic scripts, such as that from Google, they normally go bottom of the page so it doesn't interfere with the loading of the viewable contents.  I don't think there is much to gain by timing exactly the loading vs sequencing the content/any resources loading.  This is one of the many techniques, without knowing exactly what goes on in your code.

You can look into this article, https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html.

Comment: Deferred loading of resources allows  load event to trigger sooner

Answer (score 0):

Keep your scripts right before `</body>` and put all of your JavaScript in a single file.  Avoid loading several .js files.  That's it.